# Is it possible to build a PWA that can control devices via bluetooth?

Tags: angular, bluetooth, progressive-web-apps

I need to build a mobile app that can connect to bluetooth devices and send and receive data to update the settings of the devices.
I have no experience with bluetooth whatsoever.
I have built a PWA with Angular before and was thus hoping to apply that knowledge for this project.
Can this be achieved with web technologies or do I have to build some sort of native app?
My google searches are unconclusive.
If possible, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research, I have discovered that it is in fact possible to access a devices Bluetooth interface from certain browsers, using [web bluetooth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Bluetooth_API) technology.

However, this API is still very experimental and supported only by a handful of browsers such as chrome and opera. Other major browsers like Firefox and Safari do not support this feature.

Conclusively, there is no reliable way to provide a range users of a PWA (with different browsers) with features that require Bluetooth.